# how to use google analytics records from my admin panel

Tags: asp.net, google-analytics

i am new in google analytics
my problem is
suppose my website is www.abc.com and my admin is www.adminabc.com
then 
i have create google analytics account and add my website(www.abc.com) detail on it. now i have get google analytics records of my website into my admin(www.adminabc.com) then how it possible?

i am working on asp.net c# and also i have get tracking id,client id,etc....from google analytics but i coudn't find how to display google analytics charts and report on my admin panel

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2 options:

1. Track www.adminabc.com as a new site under the same google analytics account. You can switch between the two sites. See instructions here - https://sridharkatakam.com/add-new-website-google-analytics/
2. Track www.adminabc.com under the same site as www.abc.com. It will be just like another page in the same site. For that you need to report to google the same tracking id as defined for www.abc.com. Just add the tracking code with www.abc.com tracking id to www.adminabc.com pages.

Comment: Thanks for suggest me
but one more question for you
it is possible to get google analytics records and chart from my admin panel without login in google analytics

right now in my admin panel display one google analytics image and if i click on it and login with my username and password then after i will see the chart in my admin panel.

i am working on asp.net c# tecchnology

Comment: I don't think you can access google analytics records without login to the site. You can use the api but you need credentials for that as well.

Answer (score 0):

From your old account you can give access to your new account. After which you can manage it from your new google analytics account. 
For more information you can [check this out](https://joinkadir.com/add-website-google-analytics/).